# Unable to download "gms:play:services-appindexing:10.0.1"

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

I've updated the Google play services & repository but still problem is there in gradle

**failed to resolve**: `com.google.android.gms:play:services-appindexing:10.0.1`

How can i download this particular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of AppIndexing has been moved from `play-services` to `firebase`. For that, instead of using

`com.google.android.gms:play:services-appindexing:10.0.1`

use

`com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0`

Comment: Can i ask another query here to you ?

Comment: Sure, ask your question

Comment: Mr. Sneh plz help. below is my new question